# Hot objects - How to list them?

Tags: oracle

In Oracle we have the procedures `DBMS_SHARED_POOL.MARKHOT` and `DBMS_SHARED_POOL.UNMARKHOT` ([shared pool](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_shared_pool.htm#ARPLS73477)).

Is there a way of listing the objects that are "hot"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting.  I had to do some testing and viewing changes in x$kglob to find the answer.  "MARKHOT" marks the object HOT in the library cache, so this is how to find them:

```
select * from x$kglob where kglobprop='HOT';
```

or if you want to find all for a schema:

```
select * from x$kglob  where kglnaown='schema' and kglobprop='HOT';
```

Please test properly in your pre-production environments.  I remember vaguely that using it can possibly cause worse performance problems than you had to start off with.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - as an aside - is there a v$ equivalent to x$kglob?

Comment: I looked for HOT in the typical v$ views such as v$db_object_cache but could not find one.  Poking around the shared pool is hairy at best and undocumented at worst, so I imagine that they may add this to v$ at a later stage once MARKHOT gets documented properly.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question, but you can use

```
select
        hash_value,
        full_hash_value,
        namespace,
        child_latch,
        property        hot_flag,
        executions,
        invalidations
from
        v$db_object_cache
where
         property='HOT'
;
```